# Countdown resets after page reload and execute function

Tags: javascript

I have a `10` minute countdown and I need it to keep counting even if page gets reloaded or user goes to another page.
Also I need it to execute a function when counted to `0`.

I have some code that sets `10` minute countdown

```
<div id="clockdiv"></div>
<script>
    var time_in_minutes = 10;
    var current_time = Date.parse(new Date());
    var deadline = new Date(current_time + time_in_minutes*60*1000);
    var finishTime;

    function time_remaining(endtime){
        var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
        var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
        var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
        var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
        var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
        return {'total':t, 'days':days, 'hours':hours, 'minutes':minutes, 'seconds':seconds};
    }

    function run_clock(id,endtime){
        var clock = document.getElementById(id);
        function update_clock(){
            var t = time_remaining(endtime);
            clock.innerHTML = 'minutes: '+t.minutes+'<br>seconds: '+t.seconds;
            if(t.total<=0){ clearInterval(timeinterval); }
            if(t.total<=0){

                console.log('execute function');
            }
        }
        update_clock(); // run function once at first to avoid delay
        var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock,1000);
    }
    run_clock('clockdiv',deadline);

</script>
```

So I got it to the point where it counts to `0` and says "execute function" in `console.log` but it gets reset every time page reloads.

My desired result would be that the counter keeps counting even if page gets reloaded.

Comment: Javascript variables are not persistent. To make them persistent you need to store them locally with help of Cookies or LocalStorage.